# Ubuntu force shut down

Tags: 22.04

4. Recently I have force shut down a couple of times and now my vm takes a long time to boot / just freezes at the start. Is there any remedy I can do to fix the issue?

Comment: Does the VM eventually boot, or is it just stuck forever and doesn't seem to be doing anything?

Comment: sometimes it loads but it takes 10 mins+ which is way too long for me